# "list index out of range" in python

Tags: python

I have a code in python to index a text file that contain arabic words. I tested the code on an english text and it works well ,but it gives me an error when i tested an arabic one.
Note: the text file is saved in unicode encoding not in ANSI encoding.

This is my code:

```
from whoosh import fields, index
import os.path
import csv
import codecs
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser

# This list associates a name with each position in a row
columns = ["juza","chapter","verse","voc"]

schema = fields.Schema(juza=fields.NUMERIC,
                       chapter=fields.NUMERIC,
                       verse=fields.NUMERIC,
                       voc=fields.TEXT)

# Create the Whoosh index
indexname = "indexdir"
if not os.path.exists(indexname):
  os.mkdir(indexname)
ix = index.create_in(indexname, schema)

# Open a writer for the index
with ix.writer() as writer:
  with open("h.txt", 'r') as txtfile:
    lines=txtfile.readlines()

    # Read each row in the file
    for i in lines:

      # Create a dictionary to hold the document values for this row
      doc = {}
      thisline=i.split()
      u=0

      # Read the values for the row enumerated like
      # (0, "juza"), (1, "chapter"), etc.
      for w in thisline: 
        # Get the field name from the "columns" list
          fieldname = columns[u]
          u+=1
          #if isinstance(w, basestring):
          #     w = unicode(w)
          doc[fieldname] = w
      # Pass the dictionary to the add_document method
      writer.add_document(**doc)
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("voc", ix.schema).parse(u"بسم")
    results = searcher.search(query)
    print(len(results))
    print(results[1])
```

Then the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\yarab.py", line 38, in <module>
    fieldname = columns[u]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

this is a sample of the file:

```
1   1   1   كتاب
1   1   2   قرأ
1   1   3   لعب
1   1   4   كتاب
```

Comment: Have you printed the result of `thisline=i.split()`? It undoubtedly has more than 4 items.

Comment: it is better to use python csv module for this. check it out here [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot see anything obviously wrong with that, I would make sure you're [designing for error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-tolerant_design). Make sure you catch any situation where split() returns more than expected amount of elements and handle it promptly (e.g. print and terminate). It looks like you might be dealing with ill-formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the header of Unicode in your script. the first line should be:

## encoding: utf-8

Also to open a file with the unicode encoding use:

```
import codecs 
with codecs.open("s.txt",encoding='utf-8') as txtfile:
```